# Run single testNG test in IntelliJ using a test explorer similar to Visual studio

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

Is there a way to run a single test using TestNG without commenting or removing the individual tests in the testng.xml. I am using IntelliJ, and I am looking for more of a test runner similar to Visual Studio that will show the individual methods tagged with @Test so that I can run them individually. How might I be able to do that?  I am not using Junit, but TestNG

Comment: Have you checked for any plugin?

Comment: There seems to be a test NG plugin, but I'm not sure if it does the same thing that test explorer in visual studio

Comment: You may run testng classes and methods explicitly from the Editor without using the testng.xml suite configuration, does it work for you?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho how do I do that?

Comment: Explicitly by pressing run gutter icon on the left to the test (IDE will create the TestNg run configuration)